How do I make Shift+space select the full row in Google Sheets, not only a part of if?

I select a cell:



I press SHIFT+Space. I expect the full row to be selected. But only a part of it is selected:



If I press Space a second time without releaseing SHIFT it really selects all the row.


Question
Focusing on one single question: How do I make that the first time it selects all the row?

xref: Shift space does not select the full row in Google Sheets, only a part of it
it was closed there for 2 reasons:
a) they said I should ask on WebApps, not SuperUser
b) they said I should ask one single unique question

My investigation so far...
Here https://www.linkedin.com/posts/benlcollins_googlesheets-activity-7121101597350223872-0wdW/ Ben says "if you use this when your cursor is inside or next to a filled data range, it will only highlight the row within that range".
Nevertheless, I see the first hit selects "until a white cell" and the next cell is "also a white cell".

If you are improving a question for reopening it shouldn't be reposted.  This is essentially the same question that was closed.  Your original question has been reopened.

The Shift + Space key will select the current cell, and, in the event the cell to the left or right is not blank, also select that cell and continue until a blank cell or sheet side is met, in both directions. If the cells to the left and right are both blank, the whole row gets selected. It does not matter whether the current cell is blank or not.
When you press Shift + Space a second time, the whole row is selected, unless the whole row was already selected.
Google Sheets has no features to customize or modify these keyboard shortcuts.
See the keyboard shortcuts help page.

@Blindspots done.
